# Kinda Noobie : I'm trying to add an image to this card and keep the hover function but can't find a way to do it

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I currently doing an Image galery, but I don't like the current design.

I'm looking to use a Modern-Card to show the image and when hover, shows the text linked to that image (either transparent or on a dark background).

Each methode I tried, the image just take the place of the darkbackground and the hover doesn't work anymore.
or disalign to it.

css :

```
.card {
-background: linear-gradient(to left, #f7ba2b 0%, #ea5358 100%);
width: 190px;
height: 254px;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 1rem;
overflow: visible;
background: #f7ba2b;
background: var(--background);
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.card::after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
top: 30px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transform: scale(0.8);
filter: blur(25px);
background: #f7ba2b;
background: var(--background);
transition: opacity .5s;
}

.card-info {
\--color: #181818;
background: var(--color);
color: var(--color);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: visible;
border-radius: .7rem;
}

.card .title {
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: .1em;
}

/*Hover*/
.card:hover::after {
opacity: 0;
}

.card:hover .card-info {
color: #f7ba2b;
transition: color 1s;
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-info">
    <p class="title">Magic Card</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

from this website : [https://uiverse.io/alexruix/heavy-elephant-39](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Adding a  in between the div and adjusting some css

I want to insert the image with a border that isn't overlapping the image since I want to see 100% of it. While being able to hover and see the customize text of each one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean.
@edit
I change from background-size: 190px 254px; to background-size: 180px 244px;

```css
.card {
 --background: linear-gradient(to left, #f7ba2b 0%, #ea5358 100%);
 width: 190px;
 height: 254px;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 1rem;
 overflow: visible;
 background: #f7ba2b;
 background: var(--background);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.card::after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 30px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 transform: scale(0.8);
 filter: blur(25px);
 background: #f7ba2b;
 background: var(--background);
 transition: opacity .5s;
}

.card-info {
 --color: #181818;
 background: var(--color);
background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/337909/pexels-photo-337909.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600');
background-size: 180px 244px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
 color: var(--color);
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: visible;
 border-radius: .7rem;
}

.card .title {
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: .1em;
 opacity:0;
}

/*Hover*/
.card:hover::after {
 opacity: 0;
}

.card:hover .title {
 color: #f7ba2b;
 transition: color 1s, opacity 1s;
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-info">
    <p class="title">Magic Card</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes thank you!!!! is it possible to have the image "Square" instead of round but to keep the rounded card?

Comment: Yes. Set: background-size: 180px 244px; in the .card-info. If you think my solution solve your issue you can "vote up" my answer(it is up to you). Thank you in advise.

Comment: i need atleast 15 reputation to upvote, I tried multiple times! Thank you again